# why EF takes a long time in first called method

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework

i'm working at an application on web and i'm using ef to create model and accessing to DB.

1. create session var for use in session level:

   ```
   private Model.WebsiteModelContainer s_defaultModel;
   public Model.WebsiteModelContainer DefaultModel
   {
       get
       {
           s_defaultModel = HttpContext.Current.Session["DefaultModel"] as WebsiteModelContainer;

           if (s_defaultModel == null)
           {
               s_defaultModel = new Model.WebsiteModelContainer();
               HttpContext.Current.Session["DefaultModel"] = s_defaultModel;
           }


           return s_defaultModel;
       }
   }
   ```
2. use DefaultModel in code:

   return DefaultModel.Ages.OrderBy(c => c.AgeName).ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a new build of your project, the first database query executed causes EF to build views that it uses for data access.  This can cause a significant delay.  You can work around it by having EF pre-compile the views.  See [How to: Pre-Generate Views to Improve Query Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx) from MSDN.